# How to find the various fields of User object in DNN 7.2

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a new user registration form. After creating the user, I want to provide various details like username, email, company name etc in the new user registration email to the administrator. After searching through various DNN community threads, I found out that these are configured in the GlobalResources.resx in App_GlobalResources folder. I can see two fields DisplayName, Email already being used. How can I get other fields like First Name, Last Name, City of the User Object?

```
<data name="EMAIL_USER_REGISTRATION_ADMINISTRATOR_BODY.Text" 
  xml:space="preserve">
    <value>
        Date: [Date:Current]
        Display Name: [User:DisplayName]
        Email: [User:Email]
    </value>
  </data>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a feature that is called Tokens. Read more here: https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/tokens.

The first name and the last name are members of the user object, therefore you have to use [User:FirstName] and [User:LastName]. Other stuff (as the city) can be found in the Membership object, therefore it's [Membership:City].

I strongly recommend to create a resource file for your portal instead of changing the text in the GlobalResources.resx - this will be overwritten with the next update.